# Ehrhart Polynomials Modulo Prime Integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, integer-lattices

Are there any results known about computing Ehrhart Polynomials modulo prime integers?

Comment: The Ehrhard polynomial has rational coefficients in general. Do you look for congruences of nominators or denominators of the coefficients ?